# How change 1 line of code in a core module without hack?

Tags: 7, nodes

Every time I update Drupal core I get the error message,

> Notice: Undefined variable: forum_term (line 764)

I've implemented [this hack](https://www.drupal.org/node/1057712#comment-4733236) on forum.module to get rid of this problem.

How can I implement this change without hacking the core forum.module file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take 3 different strategies to mitigate the problem the hack introduces.

1. **Don't Hack/Ignore the error:** Without knowing the deeper context of when this happens, this could be (as the d.o. thread suggests) just a quirk of other contrib modules that show up during the update process. You'll need to do more investigation to see if this occurs during a critical code (e.g. a module update) and if it can be ignored.
2. **Don't Hack/Fix the error:** Assuming the error is fundamentally a part of Drupal's forum module logic (i.e. not just something caused by a contrib module), you could [submit a patch](https://www.drupal.org/patch/submit) for the module to get it fixed for everyone that has the same issue.
3. **Patch Management:** Depending on your own codebase, process, & issues, patching might be unavoidable here. If that's the case, you can [create your own patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/707484) for Drupal core and create some process where it is consistently applied every time you need to you need to update your codebase.

Comment: Thanks, good advice! I'll start by your, "Don't Hack/Ignore the error" and keep watching the Log Messages.